# Corporate Tax Futures

Tags: futures

Does anyone have any additional information regarding the new Corporate Tax Futures added to MGEX this year? There isn't many resources out there, any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Periodically, exchanges invent new futures products hoping that they'll catch on. Some do catch on and and some don't.  https://www.mgex.com/corporatetaxfutures.html has news release from March 2021 and contract description, but I can't find any data on the volume being traded. I guess time will tell.

Comment: The exchange should be able to provide all the details.